# How to show full output in terminal without Stacking?

Tags: java, terminal

I am using command line for compiling and running a Java program in Ubuntu 16.04 . whenever java program produces large output , terminal  only shows us some output (upto few lines). it automatically removes previous one. How to get complete java output in terminal only.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu

Comment: Which shell are you running your commands in?

Comment: @DhruvanGanesh I am using terminal in Ubuntu

Comment: javac filename.java for compiling and java filename for running gives the entire op/error log

Comment: @Akshay try large output . it will not show full output. try writing 100000 lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go to `Edit` -> `Profile Preference` -> `Scrolling Tab`

And tick the `Unlimited` box below `Scrollback`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After quick search I found:

Inside your Terminal Window, go to Edit | Profile Preferences, click on the Scrolling tab, and check the Unlimited checkbox underneath the Scrollback XXX lines row. then Close.